# How to cite in this thesis template!

Tags: citing, thesis, harvard-style

For short documents I've always opted for creating a `.bib` doc in conjunction with the command `\citep{}` or `\cite{}` within the main text file. However, now I have to start my PhD manuscript I am not too sure how could I add citations in the *Main Matter* so they can appear at the end of the document in the *BackMatter* as a Bibliography.

My university thesis template is the following: https://github.com/gcoulby/Northumbria-PhD-Thesis-Latex-Template

I hope you can help me. If there's a tutorial around or something similar it'd be great, as I might have to further customize my future citations...

Thanks for taking the time to read this =)

Comment: See the guide  Northumbria Students in your link. Compile `main.tex` with `pdflatex`then run `bibtex` and `pdflatex` twice. The cites in the `mainmatter` will appear  in the `backmatter`, page 14.

Comment: I've tried, and it actually compiles citations but they appear as (?)

Comment: For any document, you always get ? on the first run, run latex then bibtex then latex twice more.

Comment: Finally fixed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you guys.